# asymptotic behavior of the solution to an ODE

Tags: asymptotics

Given

$$y(t) = \frac{d_2 y_0 e^{d_2 t/\epsilon}}{d_2-\epsilon \, d_1 y_0 (e^{d_2 t/\epsilon}-1)}$$

I think that $y = O(1/\epsilon) $ as $\epsilon \to 0$. But as this is important for what I am doing and I am not used to asymptotic I wanted to double-check. Thx!

Comment: Is $d_2$ positive or negative?  Should the left-hand side of the equation be $y'(t)$?

Comment: sorry, that is actually an important piece of info. Both $d_1$ and $d_2$ are positive. Its $y(t)$, not $y'(t)$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.  Also, what time scale are you interested in?  If $\epsilon > 0$ there's a singularity at $t^* =\frac{\epsilon}{d_2} \log\left(\frac{d_2+\epsilon d_1 y_0}{\epsilon d_1 y_0}\right)$, so are you looking for an estimate which holds for fixed $t \in [0,t^*)$?  Or are you looking for an estimate which holds uniformly on such a time interval?

Comment: Both, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming that $\epsilon > 0$.)

If $y_0 > 0$ then $y(t)$ has a singularity at

$$
T(\epsilon) =\frac{\epsilon}{d_2} \log\left(\frac{d_2+\epsilon d_1 y_0}{\epsilon d_1 y_0}\right).
$$

For any fixed $t > 0$ it will eventually be true that $T(\epsilon) < t$ for $\epsilon$ small enough.  That is, each fixed $t > 0$ will eventually leave the maximal interval of existence as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.  If your application requires that you only consider $t$ in the maximal interval of existence then the asymptotics for fixed $t$ will be useless to you.

Note that there is no such singularity if $y_0 < 0$.

**Asymptotics for fixed $t > 0$.**

We have

$$
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \frac{d_2 y_0 e^{d_2 t/\epsilon}}{d_2-\epsilon \, d_1 y_0 (e^{d_2 t/\epsilon}-1)} \\
&= \frac{d_2}{\epsilon d_1} \cdot \frac{1}{\epsilon^{-1} d_1^{-1} d_2 y_0^{-1} e^{-d_2 t/\epsilon} - 1 + e^{-d_2 t/\epsilon}} \\
&\sim -\frac{d_2}{\epsilon d_1}
\end{align}
$$

as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ since

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{-1} d_1^{-1} d_2 y_0^{-1} e^{-d_2 t/\epsilon} - 1 + e^{-d_2 t/\epsilon}} = -1.
$$

**Asymptotics in a subinterval of $[0,T(\epsilon))$ when $y_0 > 0$.**

The singularity at $t=T(\epsilon)$ precludes the existence of an $O(f(\epsilon))$ bound which holds uniformly with respect to $t$ in the interval $[0,T(\epsilon))$, so if you're interested in such a bound then you must restrict $t$ to some proper subinterval of $[0,T(\epsilon))$.

One way to do this is to fix some $0 < \alpha < 1$ and consider $t \in [0,\alpha T(\epsilon)]$.

Since $y$ is increasing on $[0,T(\epsilon))$ we have

$$
y_0 \leq y(t) \leq y(\alpha T(\epsilon)) = \frac{1}{(\epsilon d_1 y_0/d_2)^{\alpha}(d_1 \epsilon+d_2/y_0)(1+\epsilon d_1 y_0/d_2)^{-\alpha} - d_1 \epsilon}.
$$

Since $\alpha < 1$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{(\epsilon d_1 y_0/d_2)^{\alpha}(d_1 \epsilon+d_2/y_0)(1+\epsilon d_1 y_0/d_2)^{-\alpha} - d_1 \epsilon} \sim \frac{y_0}{d_2}\left(\frac{d_2}{\epsilon d_1 y_0}\right)^{\alpha} = O(\epsilon^{-\alpha}),
$$

so that $y(t) = O(\epsilon^{-\alpha})$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ uniformly for $t \in [0,\alpha T(\epsilon)]$.

**Uniform asymptotics when $y_0 < 0$.**

The function $y(t)$ will be decreasing when $\epsilon < -\frac{d_2}{d_1 y_0}$, and since we're taking $\epsilon \to 0^+$ we'll assume that this is indeed the case.  As such we have

$$
y_0 \geq y(t) \geq y(+\infty) = - \frac{d_2}{\epsilon d_1}
$$

so that $y(t) = O(\epsilon^{-1})$ uniformly for $t>0$.

> **In summary,**
>
> - For each fixed $t \geq 0$ we have $y(t) = O(\epsilon^{-1})$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.
> - If $y_0 > 0$ and $0 <\alpha < 1$ then $y(t) = O(\epsilon^{-\alpha})$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ uniformly with respect to $t$ on $[0,\alpha T(\epsilon)]$.
> - If $y_0 < 0$ then $y(t) = O(\epsilon^{-1})$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ uniformly with respect to $t$ on $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Cheers, that is very useful. On second thought I think I need a uniform estimate and your calculation seems to be very useful.

Comment: @chango, Glad to help!